# Generate a Drop-Down menu based on a numeric value

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

My company offers a lot of custom products. The components that are used are based on many factors such as Operating Temperatures, Thermocouples, etc..

What I am trying to make is a form that has a drop down menu of all of the outer sleeving that we offer, but have only certain sleeving appear in the dropdown menu based on the Operating Temperature that is input beforehand.

So for example: We have a Red Sleeve, Green Sleeve, and Black Sleeve. Red has an operating temperature of 10 degrees, Green has an ot of 20 degrees, and Black has an ot of 30 degrees. If a customer puts in an ot of 15, I want Green and Black to only show in the dropdown menu. If they say that they have an ot of 30 degrees, I only want Black to show.

Is this possible?

My code for the Operating Temperature is the following:

```
<b>Operating Temperature</b><br>
<input type="text" id="temperature" onchange="updateText('temperature')" /> <font size="1">Specify Operating Temperature in °F</font>
<script>
document.getElementById("temperature").onkeyup=function(){
    var input=parseInt(this.value);
    if(input<1 || input>9999)
    alert("Value should be between 1°F - 9999°F");
    return;
}    
</script>
```

I have scoured the net and Stackoverflow and the examples I find don't provide the functions I need. I can provide more information if needed, but I would like to obtain this with Javascript if possible. I appreciate any and all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a basic example using jQuery:
http://jsfiddle.net/3egLgL7v/

I set a `data-temp` attribute to each option containing the operating temperatures. When the number input changes, I disable options with a `data-temp` value below that of the input.

Comment: My answer uses jQuery. It seems that maybe you aren't using jQuery on the page? You can add another script tag before the others that references a google CDN hosted version `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script></script>`, or you could download the file and host it locally.

Comment: Updated my jsfiddle to fix this. http://jsfiddle.net/aspt8obh/. I should be removing the disabled attribute instead of setting it to false.

Comment: That did it, thank you so much for your attention to my question and being so responsive and helpful! :D